# CAML-query to Sharepoint REST API results in "invalid audience URI"?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365api

We have been successfully using the Sharepoint REST API to retrieve items from lists for a while now, but just recently decided to integrate the ADAL.JS in order to be able to access other Microsoft APIs such as Graph, Azure AD etc.

After successfully authenticating Adal.js automatically adds an

`Authorization: Bearer eyJ..`
header to the REST calls which works fine after fiddling with permissions a bit. The app is an Angular SPA hosted in Sharepoint so this header isn't necessary but doesn't really matter.

HOWEVER, a few of our REST calls require us to also query the taxonomy and as that isn't supported in the normal Sharepoint REST API, we have to hit the (/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')**/GetItems** endpoint) with a CAML-query as request payload i.e. `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News')/GetItems`
Unfortunatelly, this does not work as the API simply returns 
`Invalid audience Uri &#39;5exx5cef-x7xx-4xxx-axxx-4xxxx2e40&#39;.`
So far my only solution is to modify the actual Adal.JS library to remove this header for this specific endpoint.

So, my questions is - has anyone done CAML-queries against Sharepoint REST APIs using Adal.JS, or ran into a similar problem and can provide any insight?

I suspect it is a configuration issue but am somewhat at loss on what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to force setting the endpoint 'https://mydomain.sharepoint.com' to null. Else, each request to "mydomain.sharepoint.com" will add a graph authorization header which be validated by the SharePoint server. Since the app is registered on the Azure AD rather than SharePoint, it will be considered as a invalid audience.

Here is the workaround for your reference, please let me know if it works on your side.

```
(function () {
  angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'AdalAngular'
  ]).config(config);

  // Configure the routes.
    function config($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainController',
                controllerAs: 'main'
            })

            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

        // Initialize the ADAL provider with your clientID (found in the Azure Management Portal) and the API URL (to enable CORS requests).
        adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
            {
                clientId: clientId,
                // The endpoints here are resources for ADAL to get tokens for.
                endpoints: {
                    'https://graph.microsoft.com': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
                    'https://mydomain.sharepoint.com': null
                }
            },
            $httpProvider
            );
    };
})();
```

Comment: Jeffrey, thanks for replying. Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. Querying SP lists and Graph works fine. 

The problem is that I cannot hit the /GetItems endpoint with a CAML-query, which is necessary to also query the Sharepoint taxonomy (not possible with the normal endpoints).

So, ADAL and CAML-queries, any suggestions?

Comment: @Jonas, in this case, you need to set the endpoint 'https://mydomain.sharepoint.com' to null, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Closer! That removed the Authorization header from my other SP requests (awesome, couldn't find how to do that anywhere). Still adds it to the /GetItems endpoint though, can't figure out why, it's a POST request though? Manually removing Authorization header here works.

Example of working after your comment (no Authorization):
https://my-own-domain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('generalinformation')/items?$select=Title,jyfo

Not working (Authorization header still, error in OP):
https://my-own-domain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('News')/GetItems

Comment: @Jonas, when calling the '/GetItems' services, try to use "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/api", if use '/GetItems' without the host name, it will mismatch the endpoint in config.

Comment: Awesome, awesome awesome. You've solved it for me. Since I have been querying a subsite (I think that is the word) - I had to also add the relative url `"/sites/dev/": null` as a new endpoint, and voila, working! Thanks for the null part and all other assistance!

You've made my life so much better, thank you! Marking as answer. :D